# Hyperlink pdf on MUPDF

Tags: android

I have build MUPDF library for android and its working fine to view a pdf but any one know how I can able to view pdf with hyper link using mupdf as mupdf said support hyperlink?????

Answer (score 2):

I had the same need these last couple of days; I wrote a small patch on the 1.0RC1 code to return a String instead of the int on. It was basically all there, but needed to change some things;

```
public static native String getPageLink(int page, float x, float y);
```

It still returns the page as the int but now as "24", soo you can parse it if you need it still.
Hope the MuPDF source gets updated soon to return a full java structure on link types etc...

You can download this: [MuPDF-Extension-1.0RC1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B759R8bSQVUkeWdJc3ZZTHU0SHc/view?usp=sharing)

The download contains the patch (as you can compile it yourselve), the changed mupdfcore.c & mupdfcore.java jni files, but also for easy use the compiled binaries for android.

Comment: MuPDF-Extension-1.0RC1 file not found.